# git add common text for the same file in two branches with little variation

Tags: git, github

I have two branches. Both the branches have almost same code. But some files have some differences(with remaining common part). Now, if I want to add some 10lines of code that is  common to both the branches, how should I add that same text to both the branches? Do I have to do it manually? Or there is some method .

Example  :

Branch master : 
a.txt file :

this is starting common line for both
this line belongs only to a.txt

Branch another:
a.file:
this is starting common line for both
This visible text is available only on branch 'another'

From today onwards, most of my work is common to both the branches . So, how can I add to both the branches ? Do I have to do it manually or is there any some good way?

Will provide more information if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: there's no other way than manually doing it in both branches

Answer (score 1):

It essentially needs to be done manually in both branches, but there is a bit of a shortcut if you do it right - create a single commit that contains only that one modification, on one of the branches, then note the SHA of that commit, check out your other branch, and `git cherry-pick <SHA>`. That essentially takes the changes made in that one commit and applies them to the other branch as well. Saves a little typing, and reduces the chance of typos...

Note, though, if you have a commit that contains other changes along with the one you're interested in, it's more difficult (but not impossible).